# glBlendFuncSeparate more transparent on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es, blending

I'm drawing to an offscreen framebuffer using

```
glBlendFuncSeparate(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE, GL_ONE);
```

and drawing this Framebuffer using

```
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

Everything works fine on Mac, Window and Linux using OpenGL, but on iOS with OpenGL ES the resulting framebuffer is much more transparent.

What could I be doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: Maybe the reason is similar to here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10032036/iphone-opengl-es-1-1-alpha-blend-make-texture-wrong-color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay fixed it. It was a stupid mistake I did myself ;)

I accidentally added `#define glBlendFuncSeparate`in one of my header files,
which caused `glBlendFuncSeparate` to do nothing ;)